# Angular - umd.js vs rx.umd.js

Tags: arrays, angular

Following Angular tutorial, one can see:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.umd.js"></script>
```

used in https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/forms.html while,

```
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

used in https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

Can someone please explain or point to a document that explains when to invoke which JS file. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UMD bundles are intended for users who write in ES5 and for those users interested in `ngUpgrade`.

There's a file called `overview.md` located at https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/, you can check over there what's its purpose. This file is not yet part of http://angular.io but it's most likely to be included in a future.

Quoting part of that document

> ## ES5 and ngUpgrade users
>
> ES5 users and AngularJS 1.x users interested in the `ngUpgrade` path can take advantage of the bundles in the [UMD format](https://github.com/umdjs/umd).
>    Those are coarse-grained bundles that combine many barrels in one final file.
>
> **Warning**: bundles in the `UMD` format are *not* "additive". A single application should use only one bundle from the above list.

In your case you would need Rx.umd.js (or the minified version if you want) and ONE of the Angular2 UMD bundles.

In the document itself there's a list/table of what contains each one.

## Update

The `overview` file, while it's not yet available in the website can be found in the repository. Check [overview.md](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-build.8516473.js/bundles/overview.md).